# Select from Table up to Midnight on the last FULL day of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To find last date in table. I tried

```
SELECT MAX(ReadingDate)  
FROM [BoilerData]
```

but obviously that's not going to return the date I want.

I need to find the last date in the table that has a full days data.

So the `MAX(ReadingDate) -1 day` up to midnight?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please see this you need a lot more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: We need some sample data and expected results (as formatted text). Oh and your table definition.

Comment: _that has a full days data_ That has meaning for you alone - none of your readers know how you make this determination.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Life intervened. I should have given more detail. My Table stores data every minute and there are 18 entries with the same dateTime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would identify that the current day is "done," since it's quite unlikely that you'll be running the query after the last reading could possibly be taken but before the clock ticks over into the next day. IMHO the only safe way to do it is to trim the time off the last reading, and subtract a day:

```
DECLARE @endpoint date = (SELECT MAX(ReadingDate) FROM dbo.BoilerData);

SELECT 'The last day we can trust has a full day of data is ' 
       + CONVERT(char(10), DATEADD(DAY, -1, @endpoint), 120) + '.';

SELECT <cols> FROM dbo.BoilerData WHERE ReadingDate < @endpoint;
```

In some cases that may mean you are getting two days ago even though yesterday is "complete." To avoid that we'd have to know more details about how you know a reading is the last reading of a given day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to get the max date without the time, and then get anything prior to that:

```
; WITH MaxDate
AS (SELECT CAST(MAX(ReadingDate) AS DATE)
FROM [BoilerData])
SELECT MAX(ReadingDate)
FROM [BoilerData]
    , MaxDate
WHERE ReadingDate < MaxDate.MaxDate;
```